# TinyMCE's style="" breaks JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, tinymce

I currently have PHP code that fetches some html from the database, it then passes this as JSON to jquery which parses the JSON. Until that moment all is good. However, if you then change some styles in TinyMCE it attaches this as style to the element. (E.g. `<h1 style="font-weight:bold">`)

Next time the script tries to retrieve this, the JSON doesn't parse, because of the double apostrophes. Is there any way to make TinyMCE not use double apostrophes?

**EDIT WITH SOME ACTUAL CODE**

PHP Storer:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($row['ipdb'],$row['usernamedb'], $row['wwdb']) or die("err");
$db = mysql_select_db($row['usernamedb']) or die("err");


$id = $_POST['id'];
$column = $_POST['column'];
$page = $_POST['page'];
$value = $_POST['value'];

$qry = "UPDATE ".$page." SET ".$column."='$value' WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($qry) or die("An error occurred ".mysql_error());
```

PHP Fetcher:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($row['ipdb'],$row['usernamedb'], $row['wwdb']) or die("err");
$db = mysql_select_db($row['usernamedb']) or die("err");


$identifier = $_POST['identifier'];
$page = $_POST['page'];

$qry = "SELECT id, textnl, texten FROM ".$page." WHERE identifier='$identifier'";
$result = mysql_query($qry) or die("An error occurred ".mysql_error());
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($result);

$textnl = $obj->textnl;
$texten = $obj->texten;
$id = $obj->id;

echo '{ "textnl" : "' . $textnl . '", "texten" : "' . $texten . '", "id" : "' . $id . '" }';
```

Comment: What double apostrophes? Could you please show some actual code, because there's no way to tell what your actual JSON looks like or how it is being produced from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use stripslashes http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.stripslashes.php. Maybe can help you.